# Possible way to create a command line tool in node.js

Tags: node.js, shell, command-line, command-line-interface, command-line-arguments

I am building a nodejs based small framework for my application. Say, the name of the framework is `coffee-cup`, situated in the folder of the same name. The folder has a structure inside. To simplify the work of developers, I want to add few command line methods. For example, consider following folder structure.

```
coffee-cup
|--config
|--cups
   |--cup1
      |--index.js
      |--report
      |--cup-config
   |--cup2
      |--index.js
      |--report
      |--cup-config
```

We see that inside `cup1` and `cup2`, there is same structure. If a developer wants to add a new `cup` called `cup3`, they will need to create a folder called `cup3` and add the underlying structure into that folder.
To automate this task, I am thinking of a way to build a command line utility like

```
$ coffee-cup new cup cup3
```

that can work on linux, windows or mac terminals.

Expected result of Entering this command in terminal: would create a new folder called `cup3` in `cups` folder and will create the file `index.js` and folders `reporting` and `cup-config` inside the folder `cup3`.

I can create folder using `fs.mkdirSync()`and file using `fs.writeFile()`.
I am however, unable to find a way to make the terminal identify the `coffee-cup` command. If terminal identifies this command, it should collect the following arguments and pass on to the nodejs file and I can continue from there. What I know is, that there exist npm packages like `inquire` which are useful in creating command line applications. But it does not help in building command line utilities like I mentioned above.

So I am looking for guidance on making terminal identify the `coffee-cup` command, collect the following arguments and pass on everything to a nodejs file. It is just like we install `npm` and then terminal starts identifying the `npm` keyword and subsequent commands like `$ npm install`. Any help by experts will be highly appreciated.

Comment: For any POSIX environment, you can use [`bin` setting](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#bin) in `package.json`. For Windows... get a POSIX environment (e.g. GItBash, WSL, CygWin...). You can use [argparse](https://www.npmjs.com/package/argparse) to easily parse command line options.

Comment: Thanks Amadan. That worked :) 
Based on your suggested method, I had explored that method more extensively on https://medium.com/netscape/a-guide-to-create-a-nodejs-command-line-package-c2166ad0452e